# Cold air on the throat and lungs

Tags: running, breathing, cold

Running in cold weather sure is painful, since the cold tends to burn my throat; afterward I usually am coughing some minor flem periodically for the rest of the day.

Is there a good way to help with this?

More importantly, is there anything about this that might be harmful in the long-run?

Answer (score 3):

I have had the same issue and found a solution that worked for me. I live in Chicago where we recently had the horrible cold snap. I was still running, keeping up with my winter routine, and what I do is wear a gator or face mask for skiing. As i breathed through it while I was running, it helped to moisturize the air as I breathed, keeping my lungs and throat warmer which was a big help. I haven't had this issue since, so this may be a viable solution if you are not doing something like this already.

As for harmful, it certainly wouldn't seem so. I know plenty of people who have had the same experience and have had no respiratory issues whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

There exists oral heat exchangers for this, see the image in the link below. I haven't found an English reference but they are easy enough to find in Sweden (where it can be very cold). I suggest you visit a store specialized towards running equipment, I'm sure they can help you.

I don't believe that this is dangerous (unless we're talking serious cold weather), but you should always listen to your body. If it hurts you or you can feel the effects for a long time afterwards maybe you should be careful.

Also see: [Breathing while exercising in cold weather](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/277/breathing-while-exercising-in-cold-weather)

http://www.marathon.se/sites/marathon.se/files/imagecache/650-100procent/sites/beta.marathon.se/files/images/upload/lungplus.jpg